# Product of two probability distribution as a zero-sum game

Tags: probability-distributions, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider a game between two players, $P$ (row player, maximizer) and $Q$ (column player, minimizer).
Player $P$ controls a probability distribution $p = \{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ and similarly player $Q$ controls a probability distribution $q = \{q_1, \dots, q_n\}$.
There is a function $S = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i \times q_i$. Player $P$ aims to choose a probability distribution $p$ to maximize $S$ and in contrast, player $Q$ aims to select a probability distribution $q$ to minimize $S$. Assuming each player knows the probability distribution of the other player, the optimal strategy (NE mixed strategy) for both players is the uniform distribution. That is the optimal strategy is: $p_i = q_i = 1/n, \forall i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ which results in $S = 1/n$.

I wonder how can I give a better explanation (or proof) that this is the best strategy.
I expect there should be an easier explanation/proof than considering it as a zero-sum game and using the Maxmin method.

Comment: I think it's probably fair to say that at the end of the day, the issue comes down to the uniform distribution maximizing entropy (among discrete distributions over this space), even if your argument doesn't end up doing that.  Start with a distribution P, and show that if it's not the uniform distribution, you can come up with a dominant strategy Q.

Comment: @nomen You mean I use proof by contradiction. That would help I think. Cheers.

Comment: I don't think you need to use contradiction.  You can, for example, show that if there is a probability $p \in P$ that isn't equal to the others, that there is a biggest or smallest $p \in P$, and use that and maybe Jensen's inequality or some other geometric facts to prove the statement directly.  But I haven't done this problem in a long time and I'm "just making it up" :-)